# How to Create http NewServeMux and run with go routine?

Tags: go

I have an issue about http.NewServeMux, I've tried to run with go routine but it's doesn't work.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func run() (s *http.Server) {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/", func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        rw.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        fmt.Fprint(rw, "under construction")
    })

    s = &http.Server{
        Addr:           ":8080",
        ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
    }

    go func() {
        if err := s.ListenAndServe(); err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
            log.Fatalf("listen: %s\n", err)
        }
    }()

    return
}

func main() {
    s := run()
    quit := make(chan os.Signal)

    signal.Notify(quit, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    <-quit
    log.Println("Shutting down server...")

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    defer func() {
        cancel()
    }()
    if err := s.Shutdown(ctx); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Server forced to shutdown")
    }
    log.Println("Server exiting")
}
```

then run with

> go run main.go

And access to http://localhost:8080/ that's always to get.

> 404 page not found

How I can solve this issue?

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps log something on connection to see if the request is hitting the server? `netstat -p` could also show you if the server is listening.

Comment: @jspcal Hi, Thank you for your advice,Well how to work with `netstat -p`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're setting up `mux` but never do anything with it:

```golang
    // mux is never referenced after you add the default handler
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/", func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        rw.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        fmt.Fprint(rw, "under construction")
    })
```

Change your handler to use your `mux` var instead of `http.DefaultServeMux` and everything works as expected:

```golang
    s = &http.Server{
        Handler:        mux, // This is the important line
        Addr:           ":8080",
        ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
    }
```